# WCF Webservice not seeing parameter

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have a WCF webservice that validates XML data using a file path as a parameter.  However when I call it it totally ignores the parameter.

Webservice:

```
namespace MyApp.Validation.WebServices
{

    public class ValidateSurveyData : IValidateSurveyData
    {
        private ValidateSurveyDataResponse response = new ValidateSurveyDataResponse();

        public ValidateSurveyDataResponse ValidateXMLSurveyData(string XMLFile)
        {
            //Validation Code
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace MyApp.Validation.WebServices
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IValidateSurveyData
{
     [OperationContract]
    ValidateSurveyDataResponse ValidateXMLSurveyData(string XMLFile);
}

[DataContract]
public class ValidateSurveyDataResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    [Description("XML Data Validation Errors")]
    public List<SurveyValidationError> DataValidationErrors { get; set; }

    public ValidateSurveyDataResponse()
    {
        DataValidationErrors = new List<SurveyValidationError>();
    }

}
}
```

In the Test Client:

[image]

When I debug the code `XMLFile` is always `null`.  In desperation I have tried `C:\MyFile.xml`, `@C:\MyFile.xml`, `@"C:\MyFile.xml"`, `"C:\MyFile.xml"` as parameters but I always get the same, `XMLFile` is `null`.  What am I missing?

**Update**

Ok feeling slightly embarrassed! the problem was not with the service at all its with the data I am passing.  `C:\XmlFile.xml` give a `null` parameter but `C:\\XmlFile.xml` gives correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the parameter in `ValidateSurveyDataResponse()` method, the signature should be like this

```
public ValidateSurveyDataResponse(string XMLFile)
```

Comment: Im willing to try anything even if I dont thing the answer is correct.  Unfortunatly this just caused a build error.

Answer (score 0):

add following line above `ValidateXMLSurveyData` function in Interface.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ValidateXMLSurveyData?value={XMLFile}")]
```

sample call

```
http://localhost:5647/ValidateSurveyData.svc/ValidateXMLSurveyData?value="C:\MyFile.xml"
```

Comment: Thought you had something here.  Unfortunaly no change.  Still `null`